# PostgreSQL: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function:

```
create or replace function functions.send_occurrence(username_a varchar(80),                                                         
                                   time_stamp timestamp, location varchar(100))                

returns table(username varchar(80), occurrences bigint) as

$$                                                                               
declare user_id int;                                                             

begin                                                                                    
select id into user_id from api.user where name = username_a;                                                                                                     

insert into api.event values(user_id, time_stamp, location);                                                                                              

return query                                                                                     
            select name, count(api.event.id) 
            from api.user left outer join api.event
            on api.user.id = api.event.id                                                    
            where name = username_a                                                          
            group by name;                                                   
end;                                                                             
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The function is created successfully, but when I'm in the psql client and try to execute it

```
select functions.send_occurrence('teste1', NOW(), 'testlocation');
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  function functions.send_occurrence(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I know many people have asked this question already, but all of the answers I've seen had to do with numeric types and conversions.

Comment: Either cast `now()::timestamp` or change the type of the `time_stamp` parameter to `timestamptz.

Comment: or use `localtimestamp()` instead of `now()`. You can also make your life easier if you declare the parameters as `text` instead of `varchar(..)` as untyped string literals are treated as `text`

Comment: An FYI, `varchar(80), varchar(100)` will not work the way you think. They will be reduced to plain `varchar`. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) in the **Notes** section.

Comment: @a_horse_without_name That would be `localtimestamp` without parentheses.

Comment: It worked, thank you all for your answers. 
@AdrianKlaver you're right, someone had told me about this already, but thank you for your remarks nevertheless.